# Web scraping using Rvest- How to deal with missing values?

Tags: r, dataframe, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape details including customer ratings from Skytrax website.
While combining into a data frame, I am getting an error. As customer ratings are not available for some attributes, it is creating unequal columns and hence the error. I want NA values to be filled where the customer ratings are not available.

My code:

```
library(rvest)
url= "https://www.airlinequality.com/airline-reviews/air-india/page/1/"
heading= url %>% read_html() %>%html_nodes(".body .text_header") %>% html_text() %>% as.character()
review= url %>% read_html() %>%html_nodes(".text_content") %>% html_text() %>% as.character()
seat_comfort= url %>% read_html() %>%html_nodes(".seat_comfort+ .stars .fill") %>% html_text() %>% as.character()
cabin_service= url %>% read_html() %>%html_nodes(".cabin_staff_service+ .stars .fill") %>% html_text() %>% as.character()
food= url %>% read_html() %>%html_nodes(".food_and_beverages+ .stars .fill") %>% html_text() %>% as.character()
entertainment= url %>% read_html() %>%html_nodes(".inflight_entertainment+ .stars .fill") %>% html_text() %>% as.character()

data= data.frame(heading, review, seat_comfort, cabin_service, food, entertainment)
```

Comment: Can maybe combine with `html_table()` to see which fields are available?

Comment: This question is interesting. But I think this is dupe. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59342737/web-scraping-in-r-programming-rvest). You can use the answer and handle the scraping. Good luck.